# Passing an enum as a parameter

Tags: c++, enums

I have a Weapon.h/cpp class. thats has an enum

```
Weapon.h
enum WEAPONTYPE {
    LASER,
    ROCKET
}
```

and I have a variable that I'd like to use to track the current enum.

```
WEAPONTYPE currentWeapon;
```

I have a function that will be called to change the currentWeapon value. The declaration in the header file is:

```
void weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE choice);
```

and the declaration in the .cpp file is

```
void Weapon::weaponSelect(Weapon::WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)
{
    currentWeapon = enumChoice;
}
```

Now the error I recieve is:

error C2511: 'void Weapon::weaponSelect(Weapon::WEAPONTYPE)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Weapon'

Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1:

---

Weapon.h

```
#ifndef WEAPON_H_
#define WEAPON_H_

class Weapon
{
public:
    Weapon(Ogre::SceneManager* localManager);
    virtual ~Weapon(void);

    void createBullet(Ogre::Vector3 cameraPosition);        //Create bullet nodes/entities.
    void weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice);                   //Function to select weapon type. Tried to have "WeaponType enumChoice" as parameter but would produce error.
    void updateBullet();                                    //Update bullet logic.

    enum WEAPONTYPE {
        LASER = 0,
        ROCKET = 1
    };

private:
    WEAPONTYPE currentWeapon;               //Enum var to track weapon selected.
    Ogre::SceneManager* localBulletSceneManager;    //Pointer to our application's scene manager
    std::vector<Ogre::SceneNode*>   bullets;        //List of pointers to the bullet nodes.
};
#endif
```

Weapon.cpp

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <OgreStringConverter.h>

using Ogre::SceneNode;
using Ogre::Entity;
using Ogre::String;
using Ogre::Vector3;

Weapon::Weapon(Ogre::SceneManager* localManager)
: localBulletSceneManager(nullptr)
, currentWeapon(LASER)
{
    this->localBulletSceneManager = localManager;
}

Weapon::~Weapon(void)
{

}

void Weapon::weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)
{
    this->currentWeapon = enumChoice;
}

void Weapon::createBullet(Vector3 cameraPosition)
{
    //Pointers to use for Quick Node and Entity Creation - Get Reused once object is attached to scene.
    SceneNode* tempNode = nullptr;
    Entity*    tempEntity  = nullptr;

    //All our Objects are spheres, so create one mesh and reuse it with each entity.
    String bulletMesh = "Bullet";
    //Procedural::SphereGenerator().setRadius(1.f).setUTile(5.).setVTile(5.).realizeMesh(bulletMeshName);
    Procedural::ConeGenerator().setRadius(0.5F).setHeight(3.0F).realizeMesh(bulletMesh);

    for (int bulletAmount = 0; bulletAmount < 10; ++bulletAmount)
    {
        tempNode    = this->localBulletSceneManager->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("RocketNode" + Ogre::StringConverter::toString(bulletAmount));
        tempEntity  = this->localBulletSceneManager->createEntity("RocketEntity" + Ogre::StringConverter::toString(bulletAmount), bulletMesh);
        //tempEntity->setMaterial(

        tempNode->attachObject(tempEntity);
        tempNode->setPosition(0,0,100 + (bulletAmount * 10));
    }

    switch (this->currentWeapon)
    {
    case LASER:
        break;

    case ROCKET:
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
Reverted declaration for void weaponSelect in both .h and .cpp to the original version without any changes suggested by other posters.

Comment: WEAPONTYPE needs to be in the Weapon namespace, or you just define the function as `void Weapon::weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
    void Weapon::weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice).
Results in the same error I'm afraid.

Comment: @craigwp2703 give us the whole class + enum declaration please

Comment: @Jefffrey, shoud I add that in the original post as an edit?

Comment: @craigwp2703 Edit your original post please!

Comment: Sorry if the code is a little unclean with the comments, It's a work in progress :)

Comment: Why's the enum protected?

Comment: The protected status was a suggestion from another question I found when googling a solution. As it goes, it offered no fixes.

Comment: It should be complaining at `void weaponSelect(Weapon::WEAPONTYPE choice)` in the class declaration. Is that the real code that produce the error?

Comment: Yes within Weapon.cpp at line 25.
void Weapon::weaponSelect(enum Weapon::WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)
{ etc... }
(enum Weapon:: was another suggestion from a poaster, but that didn't work either)

Comment: I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, correct syntax somewhere.

Comment: @craigwp2703, can you post the original version of the code, please?

Comment: Both the function declaration and the defintion should _exactly_ match, that's for certain. And if you need other classes to be able to call that function, then the enum should be public, unless you only want derived or friend classes to access it.

Comment: @splrs, the function `weaponSelect` is public. Of course the user of that function needs that `enum`.

Comment: I know, I'm stating that the enum probably should be as well.

Comment: That is not the code that is causing that error to pop up as first. Would you like to try again?

Comment: I've copied exactly what I have, and it is still giving me this error:
error C2511: 'void Weapon::weaponSelect(Weapon::WEAPONTYPE)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Weapon'
Thank you for you're perseverance at trying to fix this Jefffrey and splrs.

Comment: @craigwp2703 as first and only error?

Comment: Well the other error, which I ommited as I thought it would of been fixed with the other error, is:
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WEAPONTYPE' in Weapon.h at this line:
void weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `WEAPONTYPE` declaration on the top of the class:

```
class Weapon {
public:
    enum WEAPONTYPE {
        LASER = 0,
        ROCKET = 1
    };

    Weapon(Ogre::SceneManager* localManager);
    // ...
```

The error was cause by the fact that when the compiler read the line:

```
void weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice);
```

it couldn't figure out what `WEAPONTYPE` is. That happened because the declaration of the `enum` comes later in the class.

Also, I see you are using C++11: use `enum class` instead:

```
enum class weapon {
    laser,
    rocket
};
```

Comment: Oh dear, that is very embarrassing. Thank you for taking the time to work through that very silly mistake of mine. I'd upvote you but I'm not allowed to as a new account, Is there anything else I can do? ( I have accepted it as the correct answer :) )

Comment: enum class, thanks I'll place that in now.
I think I'll go for a walk now rest my mind :P

Comment: @craigwp2703, remember to use `weapon::laser` instead of `LASER` then.

Comment: Thank you, It's been a busy week. Honestly I'm not this bad usually ;)

Answer (score 2):

If WEAPONTYPE is declared outside the class use this syntax:

```
void Weapon::weaponSelect(WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)
{
    currentWeapon = enumChoice;
}
```

If this enum is declared within the class:

```
void Weapon::weaponSelect(Weapon::WEAPONTYPE enumChoice)
{
    this->currentWeapon = enumChoice;
}
```

You must declare the enum before using it.

Comment: WEAPON type enum is within the Weapon class in Weapon.h. It is a protected variable, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the enum, `WEAPONTYPE` to be before the deceleration of `weaponSelect`
Also, I dont understand your API: 
On one hand, you declare  `weaponSelect` as public. But, it's parameter is a protected enum. how cau users of your class can use it? this should all have the same accessibility/.